# nullable object must have a value linq to sql query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query that is throwing an error if a budget doesn't have any categories. Am I doing something wrong? Can I just set sum to return 0 if there are no categories? I'm fairly new to linq to sql.

```
var r = from rec in DbContext.budgets
        where rec.budgetID == updatedBudget.budgetID
        select new
        { 
            rec.budgetID,
            rec.totalIncome,
            totalSpent = rec.categories.Sum(a => a.amount)
        };

return new JsonResult(r.FirstOrDefault(), JsonSettings);
```

Comment: I've reformatted the code so we can easily see all of it at once. If you particularly wanted the previous formatting, feel free to revert it, of course. (I don't know enough about LINQ to SQL to give an answer, unfortunately.) Could you show the stack trace so we know exactly what's complaining?

Comment: What is the type of `categories`? Are you using EF, and if so, what version?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
var r = from rec in DbContext.budgets
        where rec.budgetID == updatedBudget.budgetID
        select new
        { 
            rec.budgetID,
            rec.totalIncome,
            totalSpent = rec.categories != null ? rec.categories.Sum(a => a.amount) : 0
        };

return new JsonResult(r.FirstOrDefault(), JsonSettings);
```